# How to change the text color and size of a pop up menu in android?

Tags: android, popupmenu

Text color in pop up menu is not changing even changed in styles.
Background color is changing with respect to the color in styles.xml but the text color and text size are not reflecting.

```
//Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.im_overflow);      
//Inflating the Popup using xml file  
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_overflow_menu, popup.getMenu());     
//registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {      
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if( item.getTitle().equals("Edit")){
            callEdit();
        } else if( item.getTitle().equals("Export")) {
            callShare();
        } else if( item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
            callDelete();
        }
        return true;
    }
});

popup.show();
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>      
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF01F0</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

But it is not changing the text color.

Comment: Finally i worked out and found the answer.

Comment: whats the answer?

Comment: Yes, what is the answer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can change the text size and color by adding this code to styles.xml and use it in manifest file. For me it worked.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF01F0</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#545656</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#545656</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>    
</style>
```

Comment: It help to change text styles, but not change popupBackground. I have to set white background.

Comment: I figured it way before. A Few days later when I saw the question got many upvotes and I thought the answer might help someone in need and then I added the solution.

Comment: this works for me. http://android-designing.blogspot.com/2017/03/customize-android-default-popupmenu.html

Answer (score 1):

In my style file:

```
       <style name="menuStyle">
           <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
           <item name="android:textColor">@color/onyx</item>
           <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
           <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ge_ss_two_light</item>
       </style>
```

In my java file:

```
        Context myContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.menuStyle);
        MenuBuilder menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(context);
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menuBuilder);
```