# change popup menu text color android

Tags: android, menu, popup, styles, themes

I am trying to change the popup menu color but it is not changing; I looked for possible solutions on the internet couldn't find any.

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, holder.imgOptions);
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_event_popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
```

The `XML` file for the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_update"
        android:title="Update Event" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_delete"
        android:title="Delete Event" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_deactivate"
        android:title="Deactivate Event" />

</menu>
```

Comment: try this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231404/how-to-change-background-color-popup-menu-android)

Comment: What you are looking for is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22320781/2319542)

Comment: try this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037418/how-to-change-the-text-color-and-size-of-a-pop-up-menu-in-android