# Change Popup Menu Items font size dynamatically Android

Tags: android, menu, textview, android-menu, popupmenu

I am creating an android app which has a popup menu and it is opened when a button is clicked and I want to increase the text size of menu items in that popup menu dynamically(based on the users input).

Can anyone help on how do that programatically?

**In my class:**

```
menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), menuButton);

            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.one:
                                 // Some Stuffs
                            break;
                            case R.id.two:
                                // Some Stuffs
                            break;
                            default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

**And my xml file is ::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fav_menu">
<group android:id="@+id/first_section" android:checkableBehavior="none" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:title="@string/sort"
    android:visible="true"

    />
</group>
<group android:id="@+id/first_two" android:checkableBehavior="none">
<item
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:title="@string/sort"
    android:visible="true"
    />
</group>
</menu>
```

Comment: see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28854648/2715073)

Comment: @Clairvoyant Thanks for ur link but i want to change the size dynamically  based on the user's input. (If dynamic means it should be programatically right?).

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with SpannableString:

```
//### format text of popup-items ###
for(int i=0;i<popup.getMenu().size();i++){
    MenuItem tmpItem = popup.getMenu().getItem(i);
    String tmpText = tmpItem.getTitle().toString();
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(tmpText);
    s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.4f), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tmpItem.setTitle(s);
}
//##################################
```

Answer (score 0):

In my style file:

```
<style name="menuStyle">
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/onyx</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ge_ss_two_light</item>
</style>
```

In my java file:

```
Context myContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.menuStyle);
            MenuBuilder menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(context);
            MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(context);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menuBuilder);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the text size by adding this code to styles.xml and use it in manifest file.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>


<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
<item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">  
<item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is not the answer i think. Can you please explain how to change it programatically inside the java class.